# How do I fetch the text parameter from the following parsed data from Twitter in PHP?

Tags: php, twitter

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [created_at] => Tue Jun 03 08:29:16 +0000 2014
            [id] => 12345656
            [id_str] => 123456789
            [text] => @abcd This is a sample tweet

)
)
```

I want to fetch the tweet (text) parameter here in PHP.

Comment: try $arr[0]->text  also post your full code what you have tried

Comment: you could try `$array[0]->text`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say this array is in the variable `$array`

Then you can access the text like this: `$text = $array[0]->text;`